# How to backup Ec2 linux instances along with users

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

Is there a way to backup users along with software created in AWS.

context:I am currently learning ansible and shutting down those instances created after some time..Everyday i have to recreate again users,,install anisble after relaunching those instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural way to backup EC2 instances is through [snapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/backup-recovery/ec2-backup.html).  You can also create [custom AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-custom-ami.html) which will simplify launching new instances with all the per-installed software of yours, along with its users and all the settings.